# Add value to bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

I am trying to add values to [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) using jQuery. I added below lines in head section, after the jQuery and Bootstrap scripts and CSS.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`
```

My HTML select code is like below:

```
<select class="chapters" data-size="7">
  <option>All Chapters</option>
</select>
```

I tried with below code to add more values to the select.

```
$('.chapters').selectpicker();
$('.chapters').selectpicker('val', 'Mustard');
$('.chapters').selectpicker('refresh');
```

However, I am getting output like below.

[image: Bootstrap select without added option]

I am not getting any error in the *console*.

Comment: You getting any errors?  You sure that `$('.chapters')` is returning the expected element?

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so that we may assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the [val](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerval) method of the [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) plugin can only be used to change the value of the select. Thus, given that you have the option *Mustard* in your select, it can be selected using `$select.selectpicker('val', 'Mustard');`.

To add an option to the select, you need to create an [`<option />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element yourself and append it to the [`<select />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) element. To let the plugin know that something changed and the UI needs to be updated, you can use the [refresh](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) method.

I have created a little demo to show you how this can be done. The below code can be used to add options to a select and will ensure that the UI is refreshed. It also allows to set the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-value) of the option to something other than the text value. You may or may not find that useful, but I hope you find it insightful to see how elements can be modified using jQuery.

```js
function addOption($select, text, value = null) {
  var $opt = $('<option />', {text: text});
  if (value === null) {
    value = text.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
  }
  $opt.attr('value', value);
  $select.append($opt);
  $select.selectpicker('refresh');
}

var $chapterSelect = $('.chapters');
$chapterSelect.selectpicker();
addOption($chapterSelect, 'Mustard');
addOption($chapterSelect, 'Ketchup');
addOption($chapterSelect, 'Mayonnaise');
addOption($chapterSelect, 'French fries');
$chapterSelect.selectpicker('val', 'mustard');
```

```html
<!-- styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
      crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- actual body -->
<select class="chapters" data-size="7">
  <option>All Chapters</option>
</select>
```

Comment: nice answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

if `chapters` is your ID then try below.

```
$('.chapters').val('Mustard');
$('.chapters').selectpicker('refresh');
```

You need to call the ['refresh'](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh) 
to programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

Comment: @abuabu - see the above answer

Comment: Thanks @Prog. but `.chapters` is not an ID, it is a class. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu - see the updated answer ...
I suggest you to give Id and then use old code

Comment: You should make it clear that most of your answer is copied from the link you provide. You could format it as a quote, for example.